# weights suddenly become nan in my implementation of ppo

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to implement PPO in Tensorflow. (Proximal Policy Optimization)

It learnt InvertedPendulum and HalfCheetah in Opengym somewhat but often the weights suddenly become nan. I don't think it's doing anything like dividing by 0 or log(0). I want to know why this happens.

For now I treat this problem with canceling the training and back to the last weight variables when the loss become nan.

```
if math.isnan(SESS.run(self.loss_total, feed_dict)): # if the loss is nan, cancel the training
                print("cancel")
                self.pull_parameter_server()
                break
```

My full code is here: https://pastebin.com/KxqVqXQF
I made this code with reference to these websites:

https://qiita.com/sugulu/items/8925d170f030878d6582#ppo%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%82%BA%E3%83%A0%E8%A7%A3%E8%AA%AC

and

http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/chou17a/chou17a.pdfs

**update**
Sorry there were some mistakes in the values of hyperparameters above:
self.learning_rate = tf.maximum(tf.train.exponential_decay(LEARNING_RATE, self.global_step, 1000, 0.99, staircase=True), 1e-6)
should be
self.learning_rate = tf.maximum(tf.train.exponential_decay(LEARNING_RATE, self.global_step, 1000, 0.98, staircase=True), 1e-6)

Comment: If you are confident on your mathematical operations, that may happen due to wrong weights initialization, very large learning rate or incompatibility between cudnn, cuda and tensorflow versions.

Comment: I am using HeNormal for initialization since the activation is relu. The learning rate is 1e-3 and exponentially decreasing. I also tried with learning rate of 3e-4 but did not work. The versions are tensorflow-gpu 1.3, cuda 8, cudnn 6. Should I change the initialization to uniform of really small number? or downgrade(upgrade) any of the versions?

Comment: And what GPU are you using?

Comment: I am using geforce 1060.

Comment: Do a sanity check for overflow in your loss. Somewhere the values are getting too large and hence you are getting nan in your loss

Comment: @Nain I checked my code. Changing r_theta = self.prob / self.prob_old  to tf.minimum(self.prob / self.prob_old, 10) incredibly decreased the frequency the weights become nan!. I also changed the learning rate to 3e-4 and batch size to 256. The weights still sometimes become nan so I keep checking my code but thanks anyway.

Comment: Also, try clipping those values

Comment: I clipped them like self.prob = tf.clip_by_value(beta_dist.prob( x ), 1e-5, 150). I still get nan but I think this is good enough for now.